# Remove consecutive array with duplicate values in multidimensional array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, duplicates

I working on a function which filters a multi dimensional array, if the successive arrays have same value, I need to remove the arrays in between and get only the first and last of the successive arrays with duplicate values.

I cant figure out how to do this.

Hope you can help me.

Thanks.

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
function removeDuplicates($array){
    $result = [];
    $count = 0;
    $firstValue = null;

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {

        if($array[$i]['id'] == firstValue){

            $result[] = $array[$i]);

        }else{

            // do action

        }

    }

    return $array;

}
```

**Sample Array**

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [key] => 0 
        [value] => 25 
        ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [key] => 1 
        [value] => 25 
        ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [key] => 2 
        [value] => 25 
        ) 
    [3] => Array ( 
        [key] => 3 
        [value] => 33 
        )    
    [4] => Array ( 
        [key] => 4 
        [value] => 45 
        ) 
    [5] => Array ( 
        [key] => 5 
        [value] => 66 
        ) 
    [6] => Array ( 
        [key] => 6 
        [value] => 66 
        ) 
    [7] => Array ( 
        [key] => 7 
        [value] => 66 
        ) 
    [8] => Array ( 
        [key] => 8 
        [value] => 66 
        ) 
    [9] => Array ( 
        [key] => 9 
        [value] => 55 
        ) 
    )
```

Here the first 3 arrays have same values (25), I need to remove the 2nd array and retain the 1st and 3rd, also with the 6th to 9th only retain the 6th and 9th array.

**Expected Result**

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [key] => 0 
        [value] => 25 
        )  
    [2] => Array ( 
        [key] => 2 
        [value] => 25 
        ) 
    [3] => Array ( 
        [key] => 3 
        [value] => 33 
        )    
    [4] => Array ( 
        [key] => 4 
        [value] => 45 
        ) 
    [5] => Array ( 
        [key] => 5 
        [value] => 66 
        ) 
    [8] => Array ( 
        [key] => 8 
        [value] => 66 
        ) 
    [9] => Array ( 
        [key] => 9 
        [value] => 55 
        ) 
    )
```

Comment: Do you want to preserve the keys?

Comment: yes please.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$array = [
        ["key" => 0, "value" => 25],
        ["key" => 1, "value" => 25],
        ["key" => 2, "value" => 25],
        ["key" => 3, "value" => 33],
        ["key" => 4, "value" => 45],
        ["key" => 5, "value" => 66],
        ["key" => 6, "value" => 66],
        ["key" => 7, "value" => 66],
        ["key" => 8, "value" => 66],
        ["key" => 9, "value" => 55],
];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    if (!isset($array[$i])){
        continue;
    }
    if ($array[$i]['value'] == $array[$i+1]['value']) {
        $j = 1;
        while ($array[$i]['value'] == $array[$i+$j+1]['value']) {
            unset($array[$i+$j]);
            $j += 1;
        }
    }
}

print_r($array);
```

Since you need to preserve the keys, for loop will throw a notice when an element is not set. This is why we first check if an element exists.

Then the loop looks for two identical values that are consecutive i.e. `$i` and `$i+1`. Once it finds them, it enters a while loop to test for 3 or more consecutive identical values. It will only unset a consecutive item if there is at least one occurrence before it and one after it. For example, it will delete `$i+2` only if `$i+3` is identical.

Hope this helps!

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, I test your code with my sample array only the first successive duplicates(values with 25) are working, but array with values of 66 is not working..

Comment: Yeah it is a mess ... sorry for that ... while I try to fix it. :p

Comment: I think it's fixed now. @user123

Answer (score 1):

You can approach this as

```
$r = [];
$lastKey   = '';
foreach($array as $k => $v){ 
  if(in_array($v['value'], array_column($r, 'value'))){
    $lastKey = $v['key'];
  }else{
    if($lastKey && !in_array($lastKey, array_column($r, 'key'))){
        end($r);
        $r[] = [ 'key' => $lastKey, 'value' => $r[key($r)]['value']];
    }
    $r[]       = [ 'key' => $v['key'] , 'value' => $v['value'] ]; 
    $lastKey     = $v['key'];
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/f6FQv

Comment: Hi, sir can you not remove the the "key" inside the array

Comment: @user123 the `key($r)` is getting the last key of the array , means the last element array, try to execute this code.

Comment: @user123 refer to this one : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.key.php

Comment: `$array = [
            ["key" => 0, "value" => 25],
            ["key" => 2, "value" => 25],
            ["key" => 3, "value" => 33],
            ["key" => 4, "value" => 45],
            ["key" => 5, "value" => 66],
            ["key" => 8, "value" => 66],
            ["key" => 9, "value" => 55],
        ];` I mean the output should look like this..sorry

Comment: @user123 solution has been updated for the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:
Your array is something like this:

```
$array = [
            ["key" => 0, "value" => 25],
            ["key" => 1, "value" => 25],
            ["key" => 2, "value" => 25],
            ["key" => 3, "value" => 33],
            ["key" => 4, "value" => 45],
            ["key" => 5, "value" => 66],
            ["key" => 6, "value" => 66],
            ["key" => 7, "value" => 66],
            ["key" => 8, "value" => 66],
            ["key" => 9, "value" => 55],
        ];
```

first, find the first and last occurrence of each value.
You need a method that travels through the array and find the exact value.
Look at this:

```
function search($search, $array)
    {
        foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
            if ($val['value'] === $search) {
                return $key;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Running `$firstOccurrence = search(25, $array)` will find the first occurrence of `25`.

Now, for finding the index of the last occurrence, we should reverse array to traveling from the end of the array. So `$lastOccurrence = search(25, array_reverse($array, true))` will find last occurrence index of `25`.

Ok, When we process each value, so, We should not process it again. So we need an array which will hold values which are processed.

***Final Code:***

```
function testArray()
    {
        $array = [
            ["key" => 0, "value" => 25],
            ["key" => 1, "value" => 25],
            ["key" => 2, "value" => 25],
            ["key" => 3, "value" => 33],
            ["key" => 4, "value" => 45],
            ["key" => 5, "value" => 66],
            ["key" => 6, "value" => 66],
            ["key" => 7, "value" => 66],
            ["key" => 8, "value" => 66],
            ["key" => 9, "value" => 55],
        ];
        $processedItems = [];
        $newArray = [];
        foreach ($array as $index => $item) {
            if (in_array($item["value"], $processedItems))
                continue;
            $processedItems[] = $item["value"];
            $firstIndex = search($item["value"], $array);
            $lastIndex = search($item["value"], array_reverse($array, true));
            $newArray[$firstIndex] = $array[$firstIndex];
            if ($firstIndex != $lastIndex)
                $newArray[$lastIndex] = $array[$lastIndex];
        }
        print_r($newArray);
    }

    function search($search, $array)
    {
        foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
            if ($val['value'] === $search) {
                return $key;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer sir,, there's error in this line `$firstIndex = $this->search($item["value"], $array);`  Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context

Answer (score -1):

Please try this hope it's work

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    if ($array[$i]['value'] == $array[$i+1]['value']) {
        $j = 1;
        while ($array[$i]['value'] == $array[$i+$j+1]['value']) {
            echo $array[$i]['value'].'==='.$array[$i+$j+1]['value'];
            unset($array[$i+$j]);
            $j += 1;
        }
    }
}
```